# Text-based game stats

Tags: python, function

I'm working on a mini-project I'm doing for fun to practice python skills and I am stuck on a problem I can't seem to figure out. I have a function that gives me the default stats for every class in the game and I want it to change depending on what class/weapon I choose in the beginning. I am still trying to learn functions so any input will be valuable. So gameStat() is the default stats while gameStat() is the changed one.

```
import time
import random
inventory = []

def intro():
    print("Hello for playing my game. It is a text based game that I am working on. \n")
    print("I hope you enjoy playing it \n")

def chooseClass():
   
    print("Please choose a class you would like to play as. Each class has a different background story to them")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Please use the number given below to select them")
    print("1: Priest\n" "2: Warrior\n" "3: Thief\n" "4: Ninja\n" "5: Pirate\n")
    

      
def classChosen(starterClass):      
    if starterClass == 1:
        print("You have chosen Priest")
        return "Priest"
    elif starterClass == 2:
        print("You have chosen Warrior")
        return "Warrior"
    elif starterClass ==3:
        print("You have chosen Thief")
        return "Thief"
    elif starterClass ==4:
        print("You have chosen Ninja")
        return "Ninja"
    elif starterClass ==5:
        print("You have chosen Pirate")
        return "Pirate"
    else:
        return None
    
def gameStat():
    health = 100
    mana = 100
    strength = 5
    magic = 5
    exp = 0
    baseStats(health,mana,strength,magic,exp)
    



def ChosenPriest(var):
    if var == "Priest":
        selectAns=""
        selectAns=input("Would you like to know the backstory? \n:Please type 1 :Yes or 2 :No\n:")
        if selectAns == 1:
            print("INC")
            #print("Since a child, you have been serving under the Church of Agathor.\n")
            #print("You didn't have much of a choice because you had nowhere else to go.\n")
            #print("You don't know who your parents are and the only thing the church would tell you that you suddenly appeared in front of the chruch with a gold cross.\n")
            #print("You still have that cross til this day.\n")
            #print("At the age of 16, everyone who serves for the lord will get their own holy weapon.\n")
            #print("The weapon is used to fight off The Shadows. The Shadows are creatures created by the Shadow Lord, Gilmah.\n")
            #print("Since the very beginning, Gilmah would rummaged through the land destorying and pillaging everything he sees.\n")
            #print("One priest was able to seal him for thousands of years but he is soon to be awaken and he'll become stronger than ever.\n")
        else:
            print("Alright!")
def Weapons(weapon):
    if weapon == 1:
        print("You have chosen Magical Book!")
        inventory.append("Magical Book")
        return "Magical Book"
    elif weapon == 2:
        print("You have choosen a staff")
        inventory.append("Staff")
        return "Staff"
    
    
def baseStats(character,weapon):
    if character == "Priest":
        if weapon == "Magical Book":
            mana=100
            mana = mana + 50
            return mana
        elif weapon == "Staff":
            magic=5
            magic = magic + 5
            return magic
#intro()
chooseClass()
userClass=None
while True:
    try:
        x=input("What class would you like to play?\n:")
        if x>5 or x<1:
            continue
        else: 
            userClass=classChosen(x)
            break
    except NameError:
        continue
    
character=ChosenPriest(userClass)

weapon=Weapons(input("What kind of holy weapon would you like to take? \n 1: Magical Book \n 2: Staff \n Use 1 or 2 to select your weapon! :"))
print(baseStats(character,weapon))
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: _So gameStat() is the default stats while gameStat() is the changed one_ I don't understand what you are asking... those two names are identical.

Comment: You return some values in baseStats, but you dont use it in the call: baseStats(health,mana,strength,magic,exp)

Comment: The parameters in the call baseStats(health,mana,strength,magic,exp) will not be updated, if that what you expect? And the variables in gameStat are local, so not known outside the function

Comment: In the gameState() function base state has 5 arguments but while you defined the base state function it takes only 2

Answer (score 0):

When you take any input it will be in string format to compare it with an integer you need to convert it to integer using int() function

I modified the code and it returns the value of "mana" or "magic" correctly

```
import time
import random
inventory = []

def intro():
    print("Hello for playing my game. It is a text based game that I am working on. \n")
    print("I hope you enjoy playing it \n")

def chooseClass():

    print("Please choose a class you would like to play as. Each class has a different background story to them")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Please use the number given below to select them")
    print("1: Priest\n" "2: Warrior\n" "3: Thief\n" "4: Ninja\n" "5: Pirate\n")



def classChosen(starterClass):
    if starterClass == 1:
        print("You have chosen Priest")
        return "Priest"
    elif starterClass == 2:
        print("You have chosen Warrior")
        return "Warrior"
    elif starterClass ==3:
        print("You have chosen Thief")
        return "Thief"
    elif starterClass ==4:
        print("You have chosen Ninja")
        return "Ninja"
    elif starterClass ==5:
        print("You have chosen Pirate")
        return "Pirate"
    else:
        return None

def gameStat():
    health = 100
    mana = 100
    strength = 5
    magic = 5
    exp = 0
    baseStats(health,mana,strength,magic,exp)




def ChosenPriest(var):
    if var == "Priest":
        selectAns=""
        selectAns=int(input("Would you like to know the backstory? \n:Please type 1 :Yes or 2 :No\n:"))
        if selectAns == 1:
            print("INC")
            #print("Since a child, you have been serving under the Church of Agathor.\n")
            #print("You didn't have much of a choice because you had nowhere else to go.\n")
            #print("You don't know who your parents are and the only thing the church would tell you that you suddenly appeared in front of the chruch with a gold cross.\n")
            #print("You still have that cross til this day.\n")
            #print("At the age of 16, everyone who serves for the lord will get their own holy weapon.\n")
            #print("The weapon is used to fight off The Shadows. The Shadows are creatures created by the Shadow Lord, Gilmah.\n")
            #print("Since the very beginning, Gilmah would rummaged through the land destorying and pillaging everything he sees.\n")
            #print("One priest was able to seal him for thousands of years but he is soon to be awaken and he'll become stronger than ever.\n")
        else:
            print("Alright!")
def Weapons(weapon):
    if weapon == 1:
        print("You have chosen Magical Book!")
        inventory.append("Magical Book")
        return "Magical Book"
    elif weapon == 2:
        print("You have choosen a staff")
        inventory.append("Staff")
        return "Staff"


def baseStats(character,weapon):
    if character == "Priest":
        if weapon == "Magical Book":
            mana=100
            mana = mana + 50
            return mana
        elif weapon == "Staff":
            magic=5
            magic = magic + 5
            return magic
#intro()
chooseClass()
userClass=None
while True:
    try:
        x=int(input("What class would you like to play?\n:"))
        if x>5 or x<1:
            continue
        else:
            userClass=classChosen(x)
            break
    except NameError:
        continue

character=ChosenPriest(userClass)

weapon=Weapons(int(input("What kind of holy weapon would you like to take? \n 1: Magical Book \n 2: Staff \n Use 1 or 2 to select your weapon! :")))
print(baseStats(userClass,weapon))
```

In the gameState() function the baseStats takes 5 argument but when you defined baseStats it only takes two arguments character and weapon which is confusing.